# Calculates start time and end time of jobs in a dataproc cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have the below function `get_status_time` which calculates the start time and the end time of the spark job which has already completed its run (status could be either fail or pass).

It's working but the function is too complex; I want to fine tune it to reduce cognitive complexity.

```
def run_sys_command(cmd):
    try:

        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True,
                                shell=True)
        s_output, s_err = proc.communicate()
        s_return = proc.returncode
        return s_return, s_output, s_err

    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e,stack_info=True)

def get_status_time(app_name):
    """returns the start and end time of the spark job running on dataproc cluster

    Args:
        app_name (str): application name
        region (str): region name

    Returns:
        list: [status_value, start_time, end_time]
    """
    try:
        end_time = get_today_dt()
        logger.info(f"the end_time is {end_time}")
        app_id = app_name

        cmd = "gcloud dataproc jobs describe {} --region={}".format(app_id, region)

        (ret, out, err) = run_sys_command(cmd)
        logger.info(f"return code :{ret} , out :{out} , err :{err}")

        split_out = out.split("\n")

        logger.info(f"the value of split_out is {split_out}")

        logical_bool,status_value, start_time= False,"UNACCESSED",""

        try:
            matches = split_out.index("  state: ERROR")
            print(f"matches are {matches}")
        except Exception as e:
            matches = 0

        if matches == 0:
            # Grab status
            for line in split_out:
                if logical_bool == False:
                    if "status:" in line:
                        logical_bool = True
                elif logical_bool == True:
                    status_value = line
                    break
        else:
            status_value = "FAILED"

        # Grab start_time
        logical_bool = False
        for line in split_out:
            if logical_bool == False:
                if "state: RUNNING" in line:
                    logical_bool = True
            elif logical_bool == True:
                start_time = line.replace("stateStartTime:", "").strip(" `'\n")
                logger.info(f"START TIME AFTER STRIP: {start_time}")
                start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                break

        status_value = status_value.replace("state:", "").strip()

        if status_value == "DONE":
           status_value = "SUCCEEDED"
        
        return [status_value, start_time, end_time]

    
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, stack_info=True, exc_info=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_status_time('data-pipeline','us-east4')
```

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Factor repeated line-handling logic out to a utility function**. Most of the
complexity in your current implementation stems from the need to (1) examine a
list of lines, (2) find a line that meets some condition, and (3) grab the next
line. You need to do that in two places, and both times you try to achieve it
within the confines of a regular for-loop using a boolean flag variable to
manage state. Any time you find yourself doing something moderately complex
more than once, consider writing a function. Even if the function mimicked your
current approach, simply factoring out that behavior would be a noteworthy
improvement. But I think there's a somewhat more intuitive way to implement the
behavior using a while-true loop and Python's `next()` function:

```
def get_line_after(lines, predicate):
    it = iter(lines)
    while True:
        line = next(it, None)
        if line is None:
            return None
        elif predicate(line):
            return next(it, None)
```

**Factor grubby parsing details out to utility functions**. The other
complexity in the current implementation
involves the parsing of
information from the output of a subprocess call. You can simplify the
primary function by shifting those annoying details elsewhere. This strategy
doesn't really reduce the amount of code (it increases it slightly), but it
increases clarity in two ways, detailed in the ensuing points.

**The primary function becomes small and clear**. It acquires a routine,
step-by-step quality. Its job is to delegate tasks to others and to log the
results. A few other notes: (1) the `region` variable was undefined in your
code, so I've added it to the function signature here; (2) for brevity here,
I've omitted logging calls; (3) restrict try-except handling to the things that
can fail beyond your control (parsing code typically does not meet that test);
(4) your code is unclear about how to respond to a failure of the subprocess
call; and (5) because we don't have your data, we can't run the code, so there
might be typos or errors in my code suggestions.

```
def get_status_time(app_name, region):
    end_time = get_today_dt()

    cmd = 'gcloud dataproc jobs describe {} --region={}'.format(app_name, region)
    try:
        ret, out, err = run_sys_command(cmd)
    except Exception as e:
        # Return, raise, or have run_sys_command() log its own exception
        # and then return data, letting callers decide what to do rather
        # than requiring them to handle exceptions as well.
        return

    lines = out.split('\n')
    status_value = get_status_value(lines)
    start_time = get_start_time(lines)

    return [status_value, start_time, end_time]
```

**The utility functions become sharply focused**. Although the utility
functions are still a bit tedious, at least they are focused on very narrow
parts of the problem. They are also easy to unit-test and debug in isolation
from the other machinery of the program. Finally, because of their narrow
focus, they tend to require the spawning of fewer intermediate variable names:
instead, their job is just to return an answer. Under
most circumstances, I would not do any logging in these
functions. An additional improvement you
could make is to convert some of the magic values (eg, the status values and
datetime formats) into named constants.

```
def get_status_value(lines):
    if '  state: ERROR' in lines:
        return 'FAILED'
    else:
        predicate = lambda line: 'status:' in line
        line = get_line_after(lines, predicate)
        if line is None:
            return 'UNACCESSED'
        else:
            sval = line.replace('state:', '').strip()
            return 'SUCCEEDED' if sval == 'DONE' else sval

def get_start_time(lines):
    predicate = lambda line: 'state: RUNNING' in line
    line = get_line_after(lines, predicate)
    if line is None:
        return ''
    else:
        line = line.replace('stateStartTime:', "").strip(" `'\n")
        dt = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed approach. I am still trying to understand the function - get_line_after

Answer (score 0):

> It's working but the function is too complex; I want to fine tune it to reduce cognitive complexity.

You've already done the SINGLE most important thing you can to reduce cognitive load--you wrote a docstring to describe what your function accepts and returns. With a docstring, I don't need to read your function. If I don't have to *read* your function, I don't care how *complex* your function is as much.

That said, the other reviews have good advice too!